# Create custom work items

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-rest-api

I need to create a custom work item type from a build task, Is this possible with current VSTS Rest API?

I have reffered the [Work items Referance](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items), It doesn't contain info on this.

Comment: Where do you run this build task? VSTS or On-Premise TFS? Creating a custom work item type via Rest API on VSTS is not supported currently. But it is supported on On-Premise TFS server.

Comment: @Eddie: Should run on both VSTS and TFS.

Comment: hmmm, then you need to wait for some time.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the REST API document and [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/06/18/vsts-process-customization-futures-june-2016/) blog about timeline, REST API for customization is not supported now.

Comment: Thanks Starrain, looks like I'll have to wait some time for this.